# is there any way to fetch records from firebase realtime database whose attribute has a value in my predefined list?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Basically what I am trying to do is I have a database with the name **users** having an attribute **username**. I have some usernames in one list and I want to show details of these users only whose username is present in the list. How can I write a query to fetch details of those users only whose username is found in this list? And note that there is no  lexicographical ordering so i can't use `startAt()` and `endAt()` functions as well.
*code snippet:*
=> myList contains usernames.
 This code doesn't yield accurate results.
Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MainModel>()
                            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("username")
                                    .startAt(myList.get(0)).endAt(myList.get(myList.size()-1)),MainModel.class).build();
```

Comment: What does `myList` contain? Can you show us how it is defined?

Comment: @AlexMamo : I have defined myList as `ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();` After creating it , i am adding entries to it using some criteria as : `myList.add(post);` where post is variable which contains usernames.

Comment: And when i print myList, there are entries there like these : ['user1','user2','user3']

Comment: now i want to fetch details of these 3 users only with username **user1, user2, user3**.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot achieve that using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter/FirebaseRecyclerOptions. However, you can use get the result of each query individually. Is that ok with you?

Comment: @AlexMamo i can't get the result of each query individually because myList can have any number of entries at run time. I am putting usernames in myList which matches some criteria. SO sometimes it can be empty or sometimes it can contain n number of entries where n is decided at run time.

Comment: In that case, FirebaseRecyclerAdapter/FirebaseRecyclerOptions are not an option. You cannot pass multiple queries to the FirebaseRecyclerOptions object.

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo. But is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, as I already said, without use of the Firebase-UI library.

Comment: @AlexMamo, can you please show me how to write the query without using FirebaseRecyclerOptions object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, the Firebase-UI library doesn't help in your case, because it doesn't allow you to pass multiple queries to the FirebaseRecyclerOptions object. So you need to perform a separate query and use the combined result.

When you are calling `.get()` on a Firebase Realtime Database query object, you are getting back a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) object. So the key to solving this problem is to use [whenAllSuccess(Collection> tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)). In your case, it should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("users");
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("username");

List<Task<DataSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (String username : myList) {
    tasks.add(query.equalTo(username).get());
}

Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
        //Do what you need to do with your list.
        for (Object object : list) {
            MainModel mm = ((DataSnapshot) object).getValue(MainModel.class);
            if(mm != null) {
                Log.d("TAG", mm.getUsername());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Assuming that you have in your `MainModel` class a getter called `getUsername()`, the result in your logcat will be all the usernames of all returned children.

Comment: i am facing the following isuue after using the above code.   `error: cannot find symbol
                        tasks.add(query.equalTo(username).get());
                                                         ^
  symbol:   method get()
  location: class Query`  Can you please resolve it? it shows "Cannot resolve method 'get' in Query".

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version ([20.0.5](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)) of the Firebase Realtime Database? If not, try upgrade it and tell me if it works.

Comment: yes it was problem with version. I just updated it and the code works fine now. But i am getting another error `2022-06-24 18:16:04.522 1253-1253/com.example.alwaqt W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 1002 found on class com.example.alwaqt.MainModel` How to resolve this query? i will be really thankful.

Comment: Without seeing the code that produces that warning, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial issue?

Comment: ok... Thank you for resolving the first isuue!